# What perl built in functions are atomic?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I'm writing some threaded code and I'm wondering what Perl built in functions and operators are atomic and safe to use on a shared variable without locking.  For example, I've been told `++`, `--`, `+=` and the like are not because they are implemented as two operations.

Is there a list somewhere?  In particular are `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `unshift` and `splice` on a shared array atomic?

Thanks.

Comment: "Splice not implemented for shared arrays"

Comment: D'oh! That leaves no atomic way to remove elements without a lock. :-/

Comment: Well, from the middle. `unshift` and `pop` work. Mind you, they surely use some kind of lock internally.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "multiple elements".

Comment: See also: [Thread::Queue](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Thread::Queue), [Thread::Queue::Any](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Thread::Queue::Any)

Comment: Oddly enough, I ask because I'm [patching Thread::Queue](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=79733). It just pushes the lock issue down another level.

Comment: "I'm writing some threaded code" - I'm sorry to hear that, Schwern. I hope you feel better tomorrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guideline: If it's an operation supported by tie, it's atomic. Otherwise, it's not.

Control:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use threads;
use threads::shared;

use constant NUM_THREADS => 4;
use constant NUM_OPS     => 100_000;

my $q :shared = 0;

my @threads;
for (1..NUM_THREADS) {
   push @threads, async {
      for (1..NUM_OPS) {
         ++$q;
      }
   };
}

$_->join for @threads;

say "Got:      ", $q;
say "Expected: ", NUM_THREADS * NUM_OPS;
say $q == NUM_THREADS * NUM_OPS ? "ok" : "fail";
```

Output:

```
Got:      163561
Expected: 400000
fail
```

`push @a, 1;` instead of `++$q`:

```
Got:      400000
Expected: 400000
ok
```

Comment: "If it's an operation supported by tie, it's atomic" why's that?

Comment: Both `tie` and shared variables are implemented using magic. (`perl -MDevel::Peek -Mthreads -Mthreads::shared -e'my $s :shared; Dump($s);'`)