# Perl Thread To Increment Variable

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have the following Perl code::

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use DateTime;

$| = 1; my $numthreads  = 20;

$min = 1;
$max = 100;

my $fetch_q   = Thread::Queue->new();
our $total = 0;
sub fetch {
    while ( my $target = $fetch_q->dequeue() ) {
            print $total++ . " ";
    }
}

my @workers = map { threads->create( \&fetch ) } 1 .. $numthreads;

$fetch_q->enqueue( $min .. $max );
$fetch_q->end();

foreach my $thr (@workers) {$thr->join();}
```

The code creates 20 threads and then increments a variable `$total`.

The current output is something like:

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 0 3 0
```

But the desired output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 .... 30
```

Is there a way to have Perl increment the variable? The order does not matter (i.e. its fine if it is 1 2 4 5 3).

Comment: You need to do an [atomic operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040333/what-perl-built-in-functions-are-atomic) or the results will be completely crazy.

Comment: You ***must always*** `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program you write. Is is an invaluable measure that will quickly highlight many simple errors that you may otherwise overlook

Comment: I do always use that. Just for this I wanted to keep my test file for SO as minimal as possible.

Comment: @Bijan And yet you left in the shebang line. There's no need to remove strict and warnings from your code snippets; in fact, you should always be copy-and-pasting exactly what you ran into your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use threads::shared;
```

```
my $total :shared = 0;
```

```
lock $total;
print ++$total . " ";
```